# How can I set if-and-or-then rule in MATLAB's FIS Editor?

Tags: matlab, fuzzy-logic

I want to set a rule using Matlab FIS EDITOR (Fuzzy Logic Toolbox) which is of the following form:

```
if .......
AND ......
OR ......
THEN ......
```

How can I set such a rule using Rule Viewer in Matlab?

P.S:   I am not satisfied with the help documentation because they have discussed with a very simple problem. e.g:If (service is poor) or (food is rancid) then (tip is cheap).... Now if you look at this statement they have used only one operator "or" ...what if i have to make such a relation:If (service is poor) or (food is rancid) and (bla bla bla) then (tip is cheap)...I am eager about knowing how to implement a composite type of statement using Rule Editor in FIS Editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the [1st result from a Google search for "Maltab Rule Viewer Tutorial"](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/fuzzy/fp243dup9.html).  It seems to address your question.

Comment: Thanks Andre for your response but i am not satisfied with the help documentation because they have discussed with a very simple problem. e.g:If (service is poor) or (food is rancid) then (tip is cheap).... Now if you look at this statement they have used only one operator "or" ...what if i have to make such a relation:If (service is poor) or (food is rancid) and (bla bla bla) then (tip is cheap)...kindly tell me how to implement a composite type of statement using Rule Editor in FIS Editor...waiting for your response. Thanks

Comment: The link is broken, and the first result for "Matlab Rule Viewer Tutorial" leads me to a place where I don't see if statements mentioned at all. If fixed I will be glad to change my current downvote.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin: This answer is quite old and I haven't used MATLAB in over 2 years, so it's quite hard to correct accurately.  Unfortunately, the site prevents me from deleting the answer because it is accepted.  If you do find the answer to the question, please edit this answer, as that would be more helpful to the community than simply downvoting :-)  I'll avoid "link-only answers" in the future because clearly they don't stand the test of time.